# Running a python thread accesses static(older) version of SQLite DB

Tags: python, database, multithreading, sqlite, python-multithreading

```
def maintenance():
    while True:
        settings = Setting.query.filter_by().first()
        print settings.__dict__


thread.start_new_thread( maintenance, ( ))
```

I'm running the above code as a thread. Accessing an SQLAlchemy model in a SQLite DB.

The code below shows a flask route.  Here I set the database table "setting" column "account_number".  In the database the values are changed successfully, however with the thread running in the background, cannot get the latest changes to the SQLite db.

```
@app.route('/dashboard/')
def dashboard():

    if session['logged_in'] == False:
        return render_template('home.html')

    account = Account.query.filter_by(account_number = session['account_number']).first()
    setting = Setting.query.filter().first()

    setting.account_number = session['account_number'] 
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    except (sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError, sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError) as e:
        print e

    return render_template('dashboard.html', account=account)
```

I have tested it externally that the SQLite DB has been changed. And it shows the changes to the db correctly.

```
@app.route('/test')
def test_setup():
    settings = Setting.query.filter_by().first()
    print settings.__dict__
    return ''
```

Does the python thread snapshot the SQLite db?  Would it be different if I setup an mysql db?